# RNSound.IsAndroid error (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native

Am getting this error- undefined is not an object(evaluating RNSound.IsAndroid)

I have already used this- react-native link react-native-sound

```
my index.android.js code is-

import React from 'react';
import { TouchableWithoutFeedback, Text } from 'react-native';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  playSound() {
    const mySound = new Sound('x.mp3', Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (e) => {
      if (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
      } else {
        console.log('duration', mySound.getDuration());
        mySound.play();
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.playSound.bind(this)}>
         <Text>Play Sound!</Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried running `react-native link react-native-sound`?

Comment: Got something?? @ARPIT

Comment: The sad thing is this is still an issue... as of the end of 2020.

Comment: @LUserWell I am here in 2023 and have the same error

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time this error means the package was not linked correctly.

To confirm if this is the case:-

1. Go to `android/app/src/main/java/.../MainApplication.java`
2. Ensure you have this import at this file `import com.zmxv.RNSound.RNSoundPackage;`
3. Ensure this method has this call `new RNSoundPackage()` as illustrated below.

   ```
   @Override
   protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
       return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
           new MainReactPackage(),
           new RNSoundPackage() // <-- New
       );
   }
   ```
4. If this doesn't work follow the manual process described in this wiki here: https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/wiki/Installation

Comment: Step 3 is important! You can auto import step 2 with Android Studio auto complete feature. And it works.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by stopping react packager, run following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
react-native link react-native-sound
rn-nodeify --install --hack
```

clean project and re-build application. `rn-nodeify` was created for non-react native packages, but in my case this works for `react-native-sound`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this bug on react-native 0.61.5:
add in Podfile

pod 'RNSound', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sound'

pod install

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

1. Delete node_modules folder of your project.
2. Update the react-native-sound dependency in the package.json file as :

   ```
   "react-native-sound": "git+ssh://git@github.com:zmxv/react-native-sound.git#HEAD"
   ```
3. fire `npm install`.

Comment: Putting the projects `HEAD` into the package.json file is not a good solution. Can you pinpoint a release or commit which fixes the issue? Also is calling `react-native link react-native-sound` not necessary after anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I am resolved this issue by manually link library in X code, actually i did react-native link that is not giving any error so assume it's linked but when i have checked xcode then see this library is not linked so when i have linked manually and create new build then it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
react-native link react-native-sound
cd ios
pod install

fixed my problem
```

Note